# How To Extract A File In A Relative Location With Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a file with python 3(for my game launcher), and this is the code I'm using:

```
import zipfile
f = open('filenamehere.zip', 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
for name in z.namelist():
    outpath = ""
    z.extract(name, outpath)
fh.close()
```

I can't seem to figure out how to change outpath to get it to put it in a relative position. ._.

Comment: Programming questions belong to StackOverflow.

Comment: It is for my game launcher. Plus, I got banned from stackoverflow for asking bad questions. .-.

Comment: You're asking a general programming question, see [help]. Just because you can't ask it on Stack Overflow doesn't mean you can ask it here (I say that kindly and respectfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
myPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'filename.zip')
f = open(myPath, 'rb')
```

It gets the current working directory and joins the file name.

Comment: Try not to answer off topic questions, I've made the same mistake before and it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: At least if it gets closed, someone will get their answer. Also, how would it not help the person who is asking the question?

Comment: It fills up GameDev with irrelevant questions and deteriorates the quality of this site. The person who asked this gets his answer and thinks he can get what he wants on SX by not following the community guidelines and has no reason to change his behavior until he gets banned from asking questions, which is what happened with his StackOverflow. In the long run it hurts the community and him.

Comment: If I had the ability, I would vote to close the question.

Comment: Don't worry, others have. Ask good questions and write good answers and soon enough you'll be able to.

Comment: @Matt Jens Jensen -.- I don't think you understand that most questions aren't related to game dev unless the context is based in game dev. For example, I asked people how to do line collision. Without me specifically saying it was for a game, you wouldn't have known it was. In _this_ case, it is for a game, and it is perfectly fine. -.- Say I was trying to make the game download maps(which would be zip files) and I needed to unzip them. It would be for a game, and you _should_ be perfectly fine with it. :/ Although, like I said, I'm making an updater. :P

Comment: @Matt Jens Jensen also please do not make accusations without looking at the proof. I did not get banned from stack overflow due to irrelevant posts, I got banned because I asked a bad question(which became popular) and it got so many downvotes that I got banned. ._.

Comment: As it says at [help], and as you surely know, generic programming questions belong to SO. Game developers do not provide better answers to this specific problem, which is a basic Python  file IO issue. It doesn't matter what the piece of code in the end is for.

Comment: Anyway, the answer worked. ^_^